# Rails - namespace setup in the config/routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my routes file I have:

```
get  "gettingstarted" => "pages#gettingstarted"


  namespace :gettingstarted do
    resource :users, :only => [:edit, :update]
  end
```

When i then load: /gettingstarted/users/edit

I get the error:

Routing Error

uninitialized constant GettingstartedController

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `GettingstartedController < ActionController` class?

Comment: I don't, I'm trying to stick with the pages controller

Comment: Can I create a controller and model for gettingstarted which won't exist in the DB? is that right?